# Profile management in Wildfly

Tags: wildfly

The domain.xml file is huge, with large `<profile>` sections. Each `<profile>` section has a lot in common.

Is it possible to split it something more modular ? My guess is **no** because the server has to rewrite the whole domain.xml file at any change, and because I've never read anything about it.

But, I'm still asking the question as it hurts my DRY developer eyes. (Don't Repeat Yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is you shouldn't edit the raw XML :) The short answer though is no.

It's best to either use the web console or use [CLI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CLI+Recipes) to manage the profiles. You can use CLI script files as well.